# ways to make getter function constant

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants, operator-keyword, getter

I'm trying to create a constant method `getValue()` which accesses a map at it's pair index and returns the value stored at `map[pair]`.
However, because `[]` is non-constant (it can change the map), the method `getValue()` can't be constant, and therefore almost my entire program can't be constant.

I tried using map's `at()`, but I'm not supposed to deal with exceptions in this program.

Is there any other thing to try?

Comment: If you can't raise exceptions, what should `getValue()` return when the key is not found in the map?

Comment: You can use `map::find()` which doesn't throw.

Comment: @gregphillip If it worked, you haven't described your problem accurately.

Comment: I just wasn't aware of map::find(). 
accessing the map with [] operator makes the function impossible to be constant, but find() allows the function to be constant, as it doesn't change the map.

Comment: Yes, but <insert my first comment>

Comment: @juanchopanza: a reasonable question, but there are lots of other options - a sentinel value, a `boost::optional` or `pair<bool, Value>`, an `assert` or `exit` in `getValue`, deliberately undefined behaviour because the programmer's certain it can't happen...

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Perhaps the most simple is to make you map `mutable`. `map::find` (as suggested in the comments) is aqnother one.